# Differentiation of a binomial-like sum with respect to m (total number of trials)?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, statistics, binomial-coefficients

I want to differentiate a function with respect to m, and I know that I have to first find a representation for the whole sum to do that since m is discrete. However, I could not find one yet. Any help?

$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \big({(1-p)}^{(m-k)}p^k - {(1-p)}^{(m-k)}p^k\big) \ln\big(x {(1-p)}^{(m-k)}p^k+ (1-x){(1-p)}^{(m-k)}p^k)\big)$

Any comment on how to simplify the sum is also appreciated.

Comment: Any idea to tell?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you you want to differentiate wrt $m$? You have an expression $m!$, it's not so easy to take a derivative of a factorial function. Your expression can be rewritten as 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \alpha  \log(\alpha x + (1-x) \beta) - \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \beta \log(\alpha x + \beta (1-x))
$$
For some $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I suggest you start here.

Comment: Basically, I try to understand what happens to the function when m increases. I know that it is not easy to differentiate the function but to understand the effect of m, I might have to do this. Otherwise,...

I will actually differentiate it also w.r.t. p, which should be easier to do, but analysis of the resultant function is also difficult. Therefore, I am looking for another way to represent the function, like Kronecker products so that easier treatment of the derivatives are possible. Btw., thank you also for your starting point, which makes it somehow easier to approach the question.

Comment: $p$ and $x$ in your equation seem likelier candidates for differentation (this seems some sort of perplexity/entropy function). If you want to see what happens wrt $m$, I suggest you look at $f_{m+1}(x) - f_{m}(x)$, i.e. discrete form of derivative

Answer (score 0):

You can take the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma(x)$ with $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. So you can write $$\binom m k = \frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!} = \frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(m-k+1)}$$ The gamma function is differentiable (which is not true for the factorial because its a discrete function).

Comment: It seems to be an interesting idea, but the function stays still very messy. I think that there might be a simpler representation so that using your suggestion can directly lead me to some conclusions.